# How do I prevent the Fn key from showing the Character Viewer in MacOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, keyboard, big-sur, emoji

I have a Magic Keyboard with an Fn key in the bottom right corner. Every-time I press it a floating Character Window with emoji shows up. How do I prevent that?

Mac OS Big Sur: 11.2.3 (20D91)

Answer (score 14):

- Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard (Tab)
- Middle of the panel is this setting: **Press [GLOBE_ICON] to**
- Pull down the drop select and choose "Do Nothing"

System Preferences (Monterey/12.x and older)
[image]

System Settings (Ventura/13.0 and after)
[image]

Comment: This also works on later versions of macOS, wherever the `function`, or `fn`, or `fn`/`globe` key has been assigned by default to `Show Emoji & Symbols`. For example, macOS Monterey Version 12.6.2, etc.

Comment: This still works more or less, but of course the system PREFERENCES display has changed dramatically. Would be great to have the instructions screenshot updated on this answer, but otherwise it still gets you there. 

SYSTEM PREFS > KEYBOARD > PRESS  KEY TO > DO NOTHING.